# AIR Socket app keeps requesting policy file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sockets, air

I am building the AIR socket server example, as [explained on this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/ServerSocket.html).
The AIR app is running fine, it creates a socket on 127.0.0.1 on port 8080.

I am connecting to the server with a SWF running on localhost. This SWF is built using the [client example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/XMLSocket.html#connect%28%29) on the same site. The SWF attempts to connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 8080 - so far so good, except that the AIR app now receives a POLICY-FILE-REQUEST:

```
Received:<policy-file-request/>
```

Since I've read everywhere that AIR does not require a policy file, why does the AIR app receive this request? And how do you reply with the proper file, from an AIR app?

Actionscript code in the SWF client:

```
 public function XMLSocketExample() {
    socket = new XMLSocket();
        configureListeners(socket);
        if (hostName && port) {
            socket.connect(hostName, port);
        }
    }

    public function send(data:Object):void {
        socket.send(data);
    }

    private function configureListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void {
        dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, dataHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
    }
```

Comment: Just an extra question for bonus points: can an AIR app function as a socketserver over the internet? Or does it only work on localhost?

Comment: Where have you read that policy file is not required?
Nevertheless, you are using SWF to connect, so the SWF always sends policy file request, as this is the way it works. Maybe you can try with another AIR (despite the fact that I don't see where it's said AIR won't need a policy).

Comment: Ok, but if I do need a policy file, how do I send it from the AIR application? There is no folder to put the xml file in to.

Comment: This is the most difficult part I had with servers - it has to both send sockets and http responses (xml policy file). Best solution I had for now is to have different ports for both things. You can check these links (some of them are very old unfortunately, but I hope it gives you at least a clue): http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html
Also: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c60.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256896/as3-sockets-policy-files
Haven't used AIR as server, sorry I'm can't give you an answer :(